# Add spelling/grammatical error to data

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, deep-learning

Basically, I want to increase the dataset I already have, containing series of sentences, and to do so I planned to add grammatical/spelling error to each sentence in the dataset. The data set i have is completely clean, i.e, without any spelling/grammatical errors. How can that be done keeping in mind that not too many errors should be added to any particular sentence and hence prevent the change in its meaning/sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [Edit Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)?

Edit Distance measures the distance between words in terms of 4 basic operations:

1. Insertion (adding a character `x`) [1 unit]
2. Deletion (deleting `x`) [1 unit]
3. Transposition (swapping two adjacent characters `x` and `y`) [1 unit]
4. Substitution (replacing `x` with `y`) [2 units = 1 insertion + 1 deletion]

For example, "algorithm" and "logarithm" are separated by an edit distance of 3.

To introduce meaningful noise that models real world data, you could consider the following approach:

1. In each string, take 1-2 words at random
2. For each random word, choose one of 4 operations and apply it randomly on any part of the word. You could also apply 2 operations on the same word. 
   In real world, you won't find errors more drastic than edit distance of 3-4.

The reason to consider edit distance is that you should make sure your incorrect spellings do not deviate from the correct spelling by more than 2-4.